# why /var/log/maillog is empty in centos8?

Tags: linux, centos, sendmail

I am used to check log in `/var/log/maillog`. (`centos7`)

But recently I updated my `operating system` to `centos8`.

Since then, I found the `/var/log/maillog` is always empty.

Is there anything i need to start manually in `centos8`? to make maillog work for me?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your logs now goes to journal, check them like so
`journalctl -u postfix`, but also check your folder permissions `sudo chmod a+w /var/log/mail*` and don't forget to do a restart `sudo service rsyslog restart`

Comment: here is the result of ```journalctr -u postfix```: ```-- Logs begin at Fri 2022-02-25 16:23:27 CST, end at Mon 2022-02-28 10:15:40 CST. --
-- No entries --```, I think the permission is good. maybe i need to start some service to start the mail process?

Comment: try reinstalling postfix but don't purge config files